# All users have their reputation shown as zero under "Users/editors"

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, edits, users

Reputation scores under **Users/editors** tab are a bit off (shown as zero), except for **filter=all**.

Apparently it's network-wide. See [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors), [Super User](https://superuser.com/users?tab=editors), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/users?tab=editors), [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors), and [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.